# Using evolutionary property in maven sub-modules

Tags: maven, properties

I have a parent pom and I've defined a property as follow

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.company.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<app.version>${project.parent.version}</app.version>
```

I have a sub-module with a dependency as follow:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.company.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>app.helper</artifactId>
    <version>${app.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Although ${app.version} properly works in parent pom and resolves to '2.1.5.RELEASE' but, in sub-modules it has been replaced by 'project.parent.version' expression and reevaluated in the current context resolved to '1.0-SNAPSHOT' instead of expected '2.1.5.RELEASE'

Comment: First question why have you defined the property `<spring.property>${project.parent.version}</spring.property>`? If you have spring boot as parent you don't need to define a property. The version for the parts like spring-boot-start-web can be used simply without a version tag at all because spring boot parent defines an appropriate dependencyManagement which handles that...

Comment: Your objection about Spring-Boot is right. But it is just an example for my issue.

Comment: So where do you really need it?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I've just updated the pom example fragments to represent the issue

Comment: So why should the `app.helper` have the same version as the parent?

Comment: If the version is related to the modules of your application you should use `${project.version}` instead and don't create a separate property. Apart from that what you have defined `<app.version>${project.parent.version}</app.version>` will result in the spring boot version ????